# How do I flatten out the four inch high bumps in my lawn?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is a lumpy lawn flattened out?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3476/how-is-a-lumpy-lawn-flattened-out)

My lawn is full of bumps, there's no stretch of flat ground anywhere. They're little mounds about 4 inches high or so, and this is not on any kind of a hill. What are some methods to fix it and level it all off?